# Interactive dependency map on rustdoc?

Tags: svg, rust, documentation, rustdoc

When I make projects with C++, I often use doxygen to generate the documentations, doxygen has a neat feature that generates interactive dependency graphs (like call dependencies, inheritance dependencies etc...)

This tool, embedded in the html docs, allows you to zoom in and out and drag things around.

I am trying to generate a dependency graph for the current crates of a project, this looks like this:

[image]

The image is generated using [depgraph](https://docs.rs/depgraph/latest/depgraph/).

I have 2 issues.

Issue 1) is, as the dependency graph grows, the image becomes harder and harder to read:

[image]

This could be solved by having a zoom and pan feature like doxygen, but I have got no idea how to generate and inject that kind of html (and maybe js?) into the autodocs from rustod.

Issue 2) is that the svg file is unaffected by the css and having the white and black color scheme looks kinda ugly, this is less important but it would be nice if the svg could mirror the css theme.

Comment: What is the scope of the question? Are you asking if this functionality exists? Then the answer is a simple no. Are you requesting the feature? Then stackoverflow is the wrong forum to ask for it. Are you asking how you would hack-together the functionality yourself? An intriguing question; rustdoc is not very customizeable so the solution would probably be derived from modifying the html and/or js files post-generation. Do you have or know of a html+js solution that is made for or could be reasonably adapted to this use case? Or are you just asking others to implement your idea for 50 rep?

Comment: Since it seems a hack would be required since it does not exist (according to you) it would be the third option. I would assume that a similar mechanism can be implemented as the one used by doxygen, since both depgraph and doxygen rely on graphviz and dot for their diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rustdoc allows for the injection of custom CSS and HTML/JS before and after the generated content. You can do this via various command-line arguments.

see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/command-line-arguments.html

To add custom HTML to the header you can use the `--html-in-header` argument.

```
$ rustdoc src/lib.rs --html-in-header header.html
```

Where `header.html` is your custom header HTML

> This flag takes a list of files, and inserts them inside the `<body>`
> tag but before the other content rustdoc would normally produce in the
> rendered documentation.

see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/command-line-arguments.html#--html-before-content-include-more-html-before-the-content

```
$ rustdoc src/lib.rs --html-after-content extra.html
```

Where `extra.html` is your custom HTML to include after the content.

> This flag takes a list of files, and inserts them before the `</body>`
> tag but after the other content rustdoc would normally produce in the
> rendered documentation.

see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/command-line-arguments.html#--html-after-content-include-more-html-after-the-content

Finally for custom CSS

```
$ rustdoc src/lib.rs --extend-css extra.css
```

Where `extra.css` is your custom css definitions.

> With this flag, the contents of the files you pass are included at the
> bottom of Rustdoc's theme.css file.
> While this flag is stable, the contents of `theme.css` are not, so be
> careful! Updates may break your theme extensions.

see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/command-line-arguments.html#-e--extend-css-extend-rustdocs-css

Unfortunately I don't have any example rust doc html - so it is hard to say exactly what should be included in your injected HTML/CSS/JS to achieve your desired results. My suggestion is that you try and if you get stuck to ask a more specific question and provide an example of the code.

Comment: @Makogan - I forgot to mention for the SVG - you could just invert the colors which should match the theme better, you can do this with the `--extend-css` - e.g. `svg { -webkit-filter: invert(100%); filter: invert(100%); }`